# Using achartengine to draw a bar graph but my last bar is squeezed out?

Tags: android, achartengine

When drawing the bar chart I end up with the last bar being squeezed out of frame, regardless of whether the orientation of the x-axis is vertical or horizontal.  I have disabled panning so maybe this has something to do with it but enabling it is not an option.

It looks like this:

[image: Graph Screenshot]

I've tried changing the margins/bar width and adding a dummy empty value to the end of the dataset, but the problem persists.  Is there a setting somewhere to fix this?

*EDIT* - I found I can actually add a dummy empty entry at the end of the series and this fixes the problem (long story short I forgot I was limiting the length of the x-axis), but this is a rather ugly solution so if anybody knows of a better one please don't hesitate to inform us!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Half of the bar is outside of the viewable part of the chart.
Set `setXAxisMax` to your `series` `.getMaxX` `+1` or `0.5` or equivalent for the YAxis usually fixes this kind of problems.

If you add a dummy value you might get a tiny line at the bottom of the graph.